# SQLAlchemy: Unable to get the first item of query

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm currently learning SQLAlchemy, and i found this strange thing. I was experimenting with a table which stores a person's name and address, and to get them i use this:

```
session.query(User)
```

And to get the first item, i tried:

```
session.query(User).first()
```

Which throws a `DatabaseError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    session.query(User).first()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2275, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2142, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2346, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2361, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 664, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 272, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 761, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 874, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1023, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 185, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 867, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 376, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
 'SELECT test_user_uid, test_user_name, test_user_address \nFROM (SELECT test_user."uid" AS test_user_uid, test_user.name AS test_user_name, test_user.address AS test_user_address \nFROM test_user) \nWHERE ROWNUM <= :ROWNUM_1' {'ROWNUM_1': 1}
```

However, i was able to retrieve what i wanted if i select all the rows, and loop through the query object:

```
users = [user for user in session.query(User)]
user1 = users[0]
```

That's all, i thought it's strange. Here's my mapping class:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_user'

    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    address = Column(String(100))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User (%s, %s)"%(self.name, self.address)
```

My best guess is that `Session.query().first()` is looking for the first row, with the generated query. However, the working method retrieves all the rows, and select the first one in Python. The problem is clearly from the generated query (invalid query). The main question is, what caused SQLAlchemy to create an invalid query?

Also, i noticed that SQLAlchemy makes things more difficult by making a query with sub-query. Is that behavior intended?

I hope i can get a satisfying answer, thanks!

Comment: No idea? Well. * *sigh* *. At least i'll have the tumbleweed badge.

Comment: It is strange that it fails. My guess is that Oracle driver is somewhat special compared to others. Just an idea: have you tried `session.query(User)[0]`?

Comment: Yep, i have. The result is the same error. Perhaps incompatible version? I use the latest sqlalchemy and oracle 10g.

Comment: Please take a look at [`Oracle: LIMIT/OFFSET Support`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/oracle.html#limit-offset-support) and try the options listed there: `optimize_limits=True` or `use_binds_for_limits=False`. I know nothing about Oracle, but I would guess that the second one should help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it didn't take me long to realize this. It turns out that it's a version problem, i was previously using `cx_Oracle` version 5.0.2 10g, i tried to upgrade it to version 5.1.2 10g, and things works fine.

This is probably an undocumented bug in SQLAlchemy, i can't find a place where they mention it.

Conclusion: If you want to use the latest version of SQLAlchemy (0.9.0b1) with Oracle 10g, you shouldn't use cx_Oracle older than version 5.1.2 10g.

Hope this helps, and thanks for reading the question!